# Drawing excircle on tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm aware that one can draw an incircle of a triangle in tkz-euclide with:

```
\tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}\tkzGetLength{r}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](I,r pt)
```

Is there a shortcut for drawing the excircle of a triangle, instead? As a reference, this is the three excircles of a triangle:
[image: excircles of a triangle]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Do you try to build something with bisector(out) and projection for example. You can make your own macros. In some days, ex circles will be a part of tkz-euclide but I need to clean some codes and to add a new documentation ( if possible in english )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work actually on a new version of tkz-euclide. Now there are ex circles

% The next version of tkz-euclide arrives with :

% `tkzExCenter(A,B,C)` defines a point center of the excircle  tgt to AB and

% `\tkzDefCircle[ex](A,B,C)` for excenter circle tgt to AB You an get a point and a radius

% You have also `\tkzDrawCircle[ex](A,B,C)`

% Example

Actually you can do that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % loads  TikZ and tkz-base
\usetkzobj{all}

\makeatletter
%<----------------------------------–>
%                     ExCenter
%<----------------------------------–>
\def\tkzExCenter(#1,#2,#3){%
\begingroup
    \tkzDefBisectorOutLine(#1,#2,#3)\tkzGetPoint{tkz@bex2}
    \tkzDefBisectorOutLine(#2,#1,#3)\tkzGetPoint{tkz@bex1}
    \tkzInterLL(#1,tkz@bex1)(#2,tkz@bex2)
\endgroup
} 

\def\tkzDefExCircle(#1,#2,#3){%
\begingroup
   \tkzExCenter(#1,#2,#3) \tkzGetPoint{tkz@ea}
   \tkzUProjection(#1,#2)(tkz@ea)
   \tkzCalcLength(tkzPointResult,tkz@ea)
   \tkzRenamePoint(tkz@ea){tkzPointResult} 
\endgroup
} 
\makeatother



\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
      \tkzInit[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10]
      \tkzClip[space=3]
      \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
      \tkzDefPoint(6,1){B}
      \tkzDefPoint(1,4){C}

      \tkzDrawLines[add=1 and 1](A,B A,C B,C)
      \tkzDefExCircle(A,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{I} \tkzGetLength{rI}
      \tkzDefExCircle(C,A,B) \tkzGetPoint{J} \tkzGetLength{rJ}
      \tkzDefExCircle(B,C,A) \tkzGetPoint{K} \tkzGetLength{rK}
      \tkzDrawPoints(I,J,K)
      \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,I,J,K)
      \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
      \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
      \tkzDrawCircle[R](J,\rJ pt)  
      \tkzDrawCircle[R](I,\rI pt)      
      \tkzDrawCircle[R](K,\rK pt)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It will be easier with tkz-euclide 2.0 because it will be enough to write `\tkzDefCircle [ex] (A,B,C)`

Comment: The \tkzDefBisecterOutLine is new to me... Thanks! My original workaround consists of a homothety of the incenter from one of the points whoops

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, and possibly the benefit of others reading this question, here is a way to produce excircles (and incircles) in plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) as shown here:

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef incircle(expr A,B,C) = 
  save a,b,c,t; pair a,b,c,t;
  a = A + unitvector(C-A)+unitvector(B-A);
  b = B + unitvector(A-B)+unitvector(C-B);
  c = whatever[A,a] = whatever [B,b]; t = whatever[A,B];
  t-c = whatever * (B-A) rotated 90;
  fullcircle scaled 2 abs(c-t) shifted c
enddef;

vardef excircle(expr A,B,C) = 
  save a,b,c,t; pair a,b,c,t;
  a = A + (unitvector(C-A)+unitvector(B-A)) rotated 90;
  b = B + (unitvector(A-B)+unitvector(C-B)) rotated 90;
  c = whatever[A,a] = whatever [B,b]; t = whatever[A,B];
  t-c = whatever * (B-A) rotated 90;
  fullcircle scaled 2 abs(c-t) shifted c
enddef;

beginfig(1);

pair A, B, C;
A = origin;
B = 89 right rotated 10;
C = 55 right rotated 72;

fill A--B--C--cycle withcolor .87[blue,white];
path c[];
c1 = excircle(B,C,A);
c2 = excircle(C,A,B);
c3 = excircle(A,B,C);

draw c1 withcolor .53 red;
draw c2 withcolor .53 green;
draw c3 withcolor .53 blue;

drawoptions(withcolor .6 white);
draw A -- center c1;
draw B -- center c2;
draw C -- center c3;
draw center c1 -- center c2 -- center c3 -- cycle;
draw incircle(A,B,C);

drawoptions();
draw 2[A,B] -- 2[B,A];
draw 2[B,C] -- 2[C,B];
draw 3[C,A] -- 3[A,C];

label(btex $A$ etex, A - (10,10)); drawdot A withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
label(btex $B$ etex, B + (18,-2)); drawdot B withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
label(btex $C$ etex, C + (-4,10)); drawdot C withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;

dotlabel.urt (btex $a$ etex, center c1);
dotlabel.ulft(btex $b$ etex, center c2);
dotlabel.bot (btex $c$ etex, center c3);

endfig;
end.
```

### Notes

The `incircle` routine works by finding the intersection of two adjacent internal angle bisectors (`c`) and the tangent point (`t`) on the corresponding side.  The `excircle` routine is identical except that the bisectors are rotated 90° so that we get the external angle bisectors.